# Error while writing Date to Image MetaData in C#-String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, image, date, metadata, gdi

Im trying to write metadata to images using the following code.But when i try to add the date field an error is thrown `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

```
using (Stream bitmapStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open,
```

Here Date is the value obtained from DatePicker.

date.tostring()->29/01/2015 06:35:13 PM

date.ToShortDateString()-> 29/01/2015

```
Stack Trace:
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapMetadata.set_DateTaken(String value)
   at myprogram.Main.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Please format your code when you post - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. Also, most of it is *completely irrelevant* to your issue. It would really help if you'd post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem (and *only* the problem).

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry.Tried my best to format the code.Its not aligning properly.Needed to add the code formatting again and again.Will try to improve.

Comment: It's just spaces... it's really not hard to fix. (I don't *think* you're using tabs...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah.But i need to break a long line and put it below,right? for example :ecoder=BitmapDecoder.Create................. otherwise it will be hard to scroll to the right

Comment: Look at my edit. It's *much* more readable. Where you've got long lines, I'd manually break them into multiple lines at appropriate points (e.g. parameter separators) anyway. (See my example with the `decoder` assignment.) Now, which line is failing? Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot :) Will improve formatting in future

Comment: @JonSkeet hmmm... call stack window is empty... Im just a beginner

Comment: Where do you see the exception? Wherever that is, there should be something showing the ability to get more details... that will show the stack trace.

Comment: @JonSkeet I handled the exception.I printed out the stack-trace from it.Please see the updated question.

Comment: Right, that's more useful.

Comment: Try using an hard-coded string, just to understand what is the accepted format. From the error and the example on MSDN I fear you have to pass the date in "US" format: MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @fog Thanks,already answered,that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception and the [example in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.datetaken(v=vs.110).aspx), I suspect you need to format this as a *US* short date. The simplest way of doing this is probably just to use the invariant culture. For example:

```
metadata.DateTaken = date.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

(Frankly it's a shame that it's a string property rather than a `DateTime`, but there we go...)

Answer (score 0):

I note that this field should be able to support hours, minutes, and seconds. Currently this code works for me.

```
metadata.DateTaken = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

For reference, I haven't specified an `IFormatProvider`, though my locale is en-GB.

The `System.FormatException` comes from assignment to the [DateTaken property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.datetaken(v=vs.110).aspx), though our overlords at Microsoft haven't decreed to document what format it wants to be in. *Hopefully underneath it's locale-invariant.*

Doing this, the date is correctly stored in metadata and accessible as you would expect in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Rather amusingly, when you set the property it requires the specific format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", but when you get it the format is the system's current one.